# How to use AES or DES algorithm on SliTaz or Haiku

Tags: python, c++, encryption, aes, haiku

How to use AES or DES algorithm on SliTaz 4.0 or Haiku

---

Sorry, but, I missed that I should include the programming environment: I want to use AES or DES in C++ or Python.

Comment: Bordering on off topic, Ivan, I am assuming that you want to program an application using DES or AES for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install OpenSSL. It's one of the most used (and more importantly, reviewed and certified) cryptographic libraries and should not take too much space. Then you can use the C interface to create your application.

Installation for Haiku: https://www.haiku-os.org/guides/building/optional-package

Installation for SliTaz: http://cook.slitaz.org/cooker.cgi?pkg=openssl

For more information about building/integration please use forums of the separate operating systems.

---

Update after C++ and Python were added as targets:

You can use openssl for your C++ needs, C libraries should be relatively easy to use from C++. Alternatively, for a more C++ oriented library, you may try and use [Botan](http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/101048/Botan-C-Crypto-Algorithms-Library-1.9.17.html).

Python already has AES and DES support in the [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) libraries, so it does not need much else.

---

Disclaimer: None of these libs have my personal preference or have been tested in any way by me.